# Unable to Deploy Mobile Application Framework to Android Emulator using Jdeveloper 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: java, android, jdeveloper, android-sdk-tools, oracle-maf

Folks I have issue deploying the MAF application on to Android emulator in jdeveloper 12c.

I have been searching for solution for 3 days now.

I have tried every solution there was out their but they didn't work.

My jdeveloper version 12.2.1.3.0

Oracle IDE  12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914

Mobile Application Framework    2.5.1.0.42.180529.1103

This is the error I am getting:

```
[12:54:08 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[12:54:08 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[12:54:08 AM] Failed to detect a connected Android emulator.  Make sure the 
emulator is running.  Otherwise, manually restart the ADB server.  The 
following results were provided by ADB:
List of devices  
attached( oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.
CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
```

I tried adb kill-server && adb start-Server and it didn't work.

Restarted my computer. That didn't work.

Installed an android device using device manager on windows 7 and that didn't work.

These are all the things I tried: Installer info, Avd setup, Tools, Tool2, Tool3, Tool4, Jdeveloper mapppings, and AVD.

I am using SDK manger installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe

Installer info:

[image: Installer info]

My AVD setup is as below screen shot

Avd setup:

[image: Avd setup]

Tools that I downloaded using SDK manager in below snap shot

Tools:

[image: Tools]

Tool2:

[image: Tool2]

Tool3:

[image: Tool3]

Tool4:

[image: Tool4]

My Jdeveloper mappings in preference

Jdeveloper mappings:

[image: Jdeveloper mapppings]

I can able to launch the android emulator with SDK manager --> Tools --> Manage AVDS --> on Android Virtual Devices tab I select and press start

AVD:

[image: AVD]

When I run adb.exe devices in cmd I see something in below screen screen which is  not right

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe devices

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

I deploy the MAF in jdeveloper 12c:
Applications --> Deploy --> New Deployment Profile --> in create Deployment profile I select MAF Android and press ok --> next screen MAF for Android Deployment profile I just press Ok.
Then again I go to Applications --> Deploy -->then I click the new deployment profile i just created and windows appears where I select Deploy Application to Emulator and press finish.

This is is what I get:

```
[10:02:36 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[10:02:36 AM] Target platform is  (Android).
[10:02:36 AM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "MAF" to Android 
emulator using profile "Android7".
[10:02:36 AM] Capturing state changes of MAF application source files in     
scope for just-in-time "Clean All" analysis.
[10:02:37 AM] A prior deployed config.json file does not exist for the 
current Android deployment profile. A new config.json file must be created.
[10:02:37 AM] A new config.json file is needed for the current deployment. 
Thus, to ensure a good deployment, any existing build and deployment output 
must be deleted for the current deployment profile.
[10:02:37 AM] Performing a limited just-in-time clean of MAF application 
build and deployment content to ensure a good current deployment.
[10:02:37 AM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[10:02:37 AM] Android Debug Bridge server already running.
[10:02:58 AM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to 
the ADB server...
[10:02:58 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:02:58 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:02:58 AM] Failed to detect a connected Android emulator.  Make sure the 
emulator is running.  Otherwise, manually restart the ADB server.  The 
following 
results were provided by ADB:
List of devices attached
(oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.
CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
```

Not sure why I can't able to deploy my MAF to Android emulator with Jdeveloper.

Please anybody can help with details. Much appreciated. I hope you folks can able to see the screen shots. Thanks.

Comment: One of the basic questions, would be, why don't you use Android Studio? That's the one supported by Google.

Comment: Android Studio doesn't support MAF development